# Bounded variables and scope

Tags: scheme

I have tried to write a procedure that gets an integer as parameter and returns true if the number is a palindrome and false otherwise and it seems to be that there is a problem with changing a global parameter's value whithin an internal function block.

```
(define index 0) 
(define (palindrome? x) 
  (if (= (lenght x) 1)
      #t
      (if (last_equal_first x)
          (palindrome? (remove x))
          #f)))
(define (lenght x) 
  (define index **(+ index 1))**
  (if (= (modulo x (ten_power index)) x)
      index
      (lenght x)))

(define (last_equal_first x)
  (if (= (modulo x 10) (modulo x (/ (ten_power (lenght x)) 10)))
      #t
      #f))
```

I would like to know what can I do about it
thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well, one problem is that you're redefining index after it's been used, in the length function. `define` doesn't really do what you want here - you want `set!`.

However, I think you'll find another bug when you try to call the length function more than once - you never set `index` to `0` after the first time, so I believe your length function will only work once.

However, this seems like it might be a homework assignment. Would you like clear instructions on fixing these problems, or would you like clues that lead you to understand the algorithm more?

Answer (score 1):

What that `(define ...)` statement does in `lenght` is create a *new* variable called "index" that is more locally scoped than the "index" you defined at the top.  That's only the superficial problem---more importantly, it looks like you're trying to write C code using Scheme.  In a simple homework assignment like this, you should *not* need to use global variables, nor should you ever have to change a variable once it's created.  Many programmers have trouble shifting how they think when first learning functional programming.

The way you've written `lenght` is not so much recursion as just a glorified while loop!  There is no point to recursion if `(lenght x)` only calls `(lenght x)` again. For example, here's how I would write `digits` to count how many base-10 digits are in a number:

```
(define digits
  (lambda (n)
    (letrec ([digit-helper (lambda (n index)
                             (if (= (modulo n (expt 10 index)) n)
                                 index
                                 (digit-helper n (add1 index))))])
      (digit-helper n 0))))
```

Notice how I *never* change a variable once it's been created, but only create new variables each time.  Since I need to keep track of index, I created helper function `digit-helper` that takes two arguments to mask the fact that `digit` only takes one argument.